# Есть ли сервис вроде web.archive.org (для бэкапа сайтов), но по заказу?

Tags: безопасность, юридические-аспекты

Для "нотариально заверенных" скриншотов сайта в данный момент.

Comment: Почта России, заказное письмо самому себе со снимками монитора/скриншотами. Письмо не распаковывать до часа Х.

Comment: @Visman вот бы почта россии сама делала скриншот... а так смысл теряется на самой первой стадии